# Onload not working: Uncaught reference error, function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, c

I'm getting the above error using this code example in C, the functions used is in src.js. When I load the webui, the error pops up for someFunction() but anotherFunction() works just fine:

```
fprintf(out, "<script type='text/javascript' src='/src.js'></script>\n"); 
fprintf(out, "<body onload=\"someFunction()\">\n");
fprintf(out, "<button type='button' id='CheckButton' onclick='anotherFunction()'>Check</button></br>");
```

src.js:

```
var check = 0;
function someFunction()
{
    req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=yetAnotherFunction;
    req.open("GET","xxx",true);
    req.send();
    setTimeout("someFunction()", 3000);
}

function anotherFunction()
{
  if (!check) {
    check = 1;
    setButtonText('CheckButton', 'Stop Checking');
    someFunction();
  } else {
    check = 0;
    setButtonText('CheckButton', 'Checking');
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the button and replace it with the onload feature. Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: what is `function()` ?

Comment: You sure that function() is defined in src.js? 
If src.js is in the same directory of the html, use just src="src.js"

Comment: `function` is a reserved word. You can't have a function named `function`.

Comment: How can you say `someFunction()` was not called? `someFunction()` doesn't outputs anything. And what exactly you are trying to achieve, a recursive ajax?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `function` is a keyword which is used to create functions. It cannot be used as name of any function.

In your `src.js`, change someFunction to

```
function someFunction() {

  console.log("someFunction")
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = yetAnotherFunction;
  req.open("GET", "xxx", true);
  req.send();
  setTimeout(someFunction, 3000);  // <== this is wrong
}
```

to call it as `fprintf(out, "<body onload=\"someFunction()\">\n");`

In `someFunction()`, you must pass a function as a parameter to `setTimeout`, not a string.

Comment: that was just an example so I edited the question to be clearer, thanks

Comment: please add `src.js` and where actually `src.js` is located ? in root directory `/` ?

Comment: src.js is in the same directory as the c file

Comment: then use `src="src.js"`

Comment: please add whatever you have in `src.js` to your question